# Gradio on Colab has Issue with package (typing_extensions)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, gradio, type-extension

I am using Google Colab T4 session , where i need my gradio app as web UI for my model.
The Notebook was OK , which means it was Running without any ERROR in the start , But one day suddenly it started Showing the following

ERROR:-

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_runtime.py:184: UserWarning: Pydantic is installed but cannot be imported. Please check your installation. `huggingface_hub` will default to not using Pydantic. Error message: '{e}'
  warnings.warn(
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-d705c8d6a1a0> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import gradio as gr
      2 def input(area,bedroom,bathrooms,parking,stories):
      3   input = [area,bedroom,bathrooms,parking,stories]
      4   output = lm.predict([input])
      5   return int(output)

18 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/_internal/_core_utils.py in <module>
     14 from pydantic_core import CoreSchema, core_schema
     15 from pydantic_core import validate_core_schema as _validate_core_schema
---> 16 from typing_extensions import TypeAliasType, TypeGuard, get_args, get_origin
     17 
     18 from . import _repr

ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

- Link to the Colab Notebook :- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rT8TELfQAj7xiYedvluOFyr-D9ZOE-4_?usp=sharing
- Link to the DataSet used :- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-k4QcjIGPtfFHrRuSsaSTWYGeCve7qoa/view?usp=sharing

Reasons for the Error (According to me)
Due to Colab resent update create a clash of type_extension version

I tried to Make a Gradio app that Can predict House Price based on the Trained model